# Sparrow Wallet only partially supports Taproot?

Tags: wallet-recovery, mnemonic-seed, wasabi-wallet, sparrow-wallet

Sparrow 1.7.1

I decided to try out the Sparrow Wallet. Since Sparrow supports `P2WPKH`, `P2WSH` and `P2TR` I created one of each and verified that it was connecting to my Bitcoin Core node.

However, I only verified the connection to the node for the `P2WPKH` wallet. Since the connection parameters are the same regardless of which wallet I am using, I figured it would connect just as well no matter which wallet I use.

I sent a small amount of bitcoin to a `P2TR` Receive address. After a while I could see in a block explorer that the transaction succeeded. So I tried to refresh my Sparrow Taproot balance and it told me it could not connect to Bitcoin Core. It had been able to connect earlier, so I checked the log file.

The log file says:

```
Taproot wallets are not yet supported when connecting to Bitcoin Core
```

If I had known that earlier, I would have used a different transaction type.

So I tried to enter the same 24 words into the Wasabi Wallet, thinking I might be able to use the UTXO from there. But when I entered the 24 words into Wasabi, it told me the word list is not valid. I double checked it in Sparrow. It is the correct word list. **[Edit: Apparently, I made two consecutive mistakes entering the word list into Wasabi. So they both do indeed use standard BIP39 word lists.]**

Do Sparrow and Wasabi use different types of word lists?

How can I make these funds spendable if I only have the 24 word seed but the Sparrow Wallet that created the 24 words can't see the balance because the current version can't yet connect to a Bitcoin Core node?

Comment: I think it's great that you tell us what you have tried already to recover, but whether “Sparrow and Wasabi use different types of word lists” seems like a good question to ask as a separate topic. Sorry that you're forced to hodl. I'll see if I can ping Craig to take a look.

Comment: I can't reproduce the word list problem today. It happened twice with the same word list yesterday, so I must have made at least one mistake twice in a row. So it looks like both wallets do use standard BIP39 word lists. But the main question was answered below. This version of Sparrow can't use Bitcoin Core for Taproot wallets.

Comment: Yeah all good, looks like you got all your answers in one place after all :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, you cannot load a Taproot wallet when connecting to Bitcoin Core in Sparrow v1.7.1. Support is planned however. For now, you can load the wallet by connecting to any Electrum server, or wait for the upcoming release.

Sparrow supports entering BIP39 word lists as seeds.

Answer (score 2):

On the Wasabi side, it supports BIP39. You can verify it by simply generating a random BIP39 word list here https://iancoleman.io/bip39/ and try to recover it in Wasabi.

I know you know but just in case: DO NOT USE THAT WALLET generated online.